# Bind to observable property, but show a non-observable sub-property

Tags: c#, mvvm, winui-3

I am trying to write an MVVM and WinUI3 based app. I have a ViewModel property, SelectedFolder, which is observable (using MVVM Toolkit). This is of type Folder which is a plain old class. Something like this:

```
public class ViewModel: ObservableRecipient {
    private Folder selectedFolder;
    public FolderModel SelectedFolder
    {
        get => selectedFolder;
        set => SetProperty(ref selectedFolder, value, true);
    }
}
public class FolderModel {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now in my XAML, I want to bind on `ViewModel.SelectedFolder`, and react to changes on it, but I want to show `ViewModel.SelectedFolder.Name`. So I am looking for something like this (which doesn't exist):

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ViewModel.SelectedFolder,Property=Name" />
```

How can I achive that? Things I thought about:

- Just make everything observable. This worked, but I am trying to avoid this, in order to decouple my model and my viewmodel. The reason is that my real model is a lot more complicated than this example, and I am trying to keep it close to what make sense for my "business logic", and to make my viewmodel cater to my view's needs.
- Make another "folder" class for my ViewModel's needs which has observable properties. I don't want to do this because it would duplicate a lot of code.
- Add an observable string property to my ViewModel: "SelectedFolderName".
- Abuse converters and write a GetNamePropertyConverter, which seems really silly.

Comment: Making a model observable whose changes you want to be observable seems like the most straightforward design choice here. You wouldn't need to make every property observable.

Comment: Yes, but the properties of Folder aren't going to change, it's basically immutable. I want to swap out the whole object instead.

Comment: Because your ViewModel is observable, when `SelectedFolder` changes, the new `Name` property value will be shown in the UI if you bind to it as `{Binding ViewModel.SelectedFolder.Name}`. You don't need to do anything else if you only want the data-bound value of `Name` to change when `SelectedFolder` is set to a new value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding to the `Name` property of the model like this should work since you are setting the `SelectedFolder` and raise the `PropertyChanged` event for it:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ViewModel.SelectedFolder.Name} " />
```

In general, you should not bind directly to model objects that contain "business logic". Instead you should wrap your model property in the view model and bind to the wrapper properties:

```
public class ViewModel : ObservableRecipient
{
    private Folder selectedFolder;
    public FolderModel SelectedFolder
    {
        get => selectedFolder;
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref selectedFolder, value, true);
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FolderName));
        }
    }

    public string FolderName => selectedFolder?.Name;
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding FolderName}" />
```

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. I created a new project and it works. I think I might have been hitting some bug in WinUI3 1.0 Preview. I've also had crashes related to bindings (https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/3680). Of course it's also possible that I just had a stupid typo somewhere...